# MappingException hibernate mapping columns

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mariadb

I'm struggling with following issue:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key
>   (FKj4uw5b6ekvxc2djohvon7lk7:bi_person_country_countries
>   [person_country_id])) must have same number of columns as the
>   referenced primary key (bi_person_country [country_id,person_id])

I created 4 models:

```
@Table(name = "bi_country")
@Entity
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "bi_person_country", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "country_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"))
    private Set<Person> persons;
```

Gender:

```
@Table(name = "bi_gender")
@Entity
public class Gender {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

Person:

```
@Table(name = "bi_person")
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "additional_info")
    private String additionalInfo;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "persons")
    private Set<Country> countries;

    @ManyToOne
    private Gender gender;
```

PersonCountry:

```
@Table(name = "bi_person_country")
@Entity
public class PersonCountry {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Country> countries;
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the `PersonCountry` class here as you are using `@ManyToMany` in both cases being `Person` and `Country` mappings.

If you have to keep it for some reason.. the linking table should not contain `@OneToMany` / `@ManyToMany` mappings, so you would have:

```
@ManyToOne
private Person person;

@ManyToOne
private Country country;
```

Keep in mind you may need to use @JoinColumn also if the database names are different than `person_id` and `country_id`.

Comment: Thank you Maćku for the good answer. I deleted my PersonCountry class and now I got: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet" . How my classes should look like?